# Accessing Custom Filters when using a mobile Web Browser

Tags: support, mobile-web, custom-filter

When using Stack Overflow on my PC, I can see my custom filters in the right-hand column.

When using Stack Overflow on my mobile (using either Chrome or DuckDuckGo), the layout is different and I can't find my custom filters.

Are these filters available when using a mobile browser and, if they are, where do I find them?

Response to answer with screenshot:
My browser doesn't show the "more" option:
[image]

Response to answer suggesting scrolling to the bottom:
There is nothing there
[image]

Comment: You're using the old layout, click the "full site" button in the footer, and then ensure responsiveness is enabled (another footer in the button)

Comment: Thank you, that sorted it. I'll tick your answer as correct to give you credit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Navigate to the questions page using the hamburger menu in the top left of Stack Overflow, this will get you to the list of all questions. Once there, use the *More* dropdown and you'll find Custom Filters at the bottom.

[image: "More" dropdown on the Stack Overflow Questions page]

Comment: Responded to this in my question - not visible in my browser (unless I'm looking in the wrong place)

Comment: @NickW Responded in a comment under your question already

Answer (score 0):

Go to the bottom of the page and click on "full site". Then, in this view on mobile, everything from the right sidebar is relocated below the main content. Keep scrolling and you'll find it eventually — it's under the links to the blog and meta (featured on meta/hot meta posts) on any page that lists questions ([home](https://stackoverflow.com/)/[questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions)).

Comment: Responded to this in my question - not visible in my browser (unless I'm looking in the wrong place)

Comment: @NickW updated.